# How to parse file name in powerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powerbi

This is the name of my file **myregistration_20180105041258_NOTIFICATION_1.zip** and 20180105041258 the numbers are a timestamp. I've so many files of this format. These files will be posted to my share path every day. I've automated to download all the files. But I want to download daily files with help of date. Can anyone suggest me how can I do this using power shell???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have got this right, then your requirement is to change the numbers(in the file names) which are actually a timestamp, into a `datetime` format and the use this to download the files or do whatever operation you deem to.

For that, I would use the `-split` parameter to get the number from the filename and then convert the number into `datetime` format using the `PoSh` `ParseExact` function. The code will look something like this.

```
$string = " myregistration_20180105041258_NOTIFICATION_1.zip"
$array = @($string.Split('_'))
$datetime = [datetime]::parseexact($array[1], 'yyyyMMddhhmmss', $null)
```

Now your `$datetime` variable will contain the date of the corresponding file and you can use this to proceed further. If you have a bunch of files, you can loop through each of them using a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

For example: 

`$original = "myregistration_20180105041258_NOTIFICATION_1.zip";
$trimmed = $original | Select-String -Pattern "myregistration" -InputObject {$_.TrimEnd("whatever you want to trim")}`

P.S. It's possible also if you need to get the timestamp only to say: 
`$original -match "\d"` and pull the value of it from `$Matches[0]`.

Comment: This is helping a bit and I want to match original string date(20180105) excluding timestamp with current date is that possible.???

Comment: `$datetime.ToShortDateString()`

Comment: `$original -match "\d{1,8}"`
then `$date = $Matches[0]`
then you can do `$date = [datetime]::parseexact($date, "yyyyMMdd", $null)`
and finally you can compare with current date in an "if" statement or whatever (For example: `$date -eq [datetime]::Now`)